# Zabbix Trigger Hysteresis - Not returning to normal

Tags: zabbix

I have the following to prevent agent connectivity from flapping (it must be solid for 20 mintutes before marking as OK).

After correcting the syntax from [Zabbix Trigger Hysteresis - Incorrect trigger expression](https://serverfault.com/questions/852496/zabbix-trigger-hysteresis-incorrect-trigger-expression) I have the following:

`({TRIGGER.VALUE}=0 and {Template App Zabbix Agent:agent.ping.nodata(5m)}=1) or ({TRIGGER.VALUE}=1 and {Template App Zabbix Agent:agent.ping.min(20m)}=1)`

Whilst it fires initially when there is no data, it never recovers. I am using v3.0.9 at the moment so trying to work with the above for now.

I have checked under the targets latest agent data, and can see agent ping is indeed `1` for more than 20 minutes.

Any ideas what i have done wrong please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zabbix Trigger Hysteresis - Incorrect trigger expression](https://serverfault.com/questions/852496/zabbix-trigger-hysteresis-incorrect-trigger-expression)

Comment: @MadHatter the first one was an issue with syntax which was answered. But now logically it doesn't work so expanded in more detail

Comment: Fair enough, but it would be a good idea to link to your earlier question, and to clarify that this is a follow-up issue after the earlier solution.

Comment: Done mate, edited and linked back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some experiments:

The agent.ping writes a "1" value if reachable and doesn't write anything if unreachable; so even if your agent is unreachable for 2 hours, the last value is 1.
This means that .min(), .avg() etc... always works on a list of "1" values.

The .nodata() function does not help with rebounds as well: it returns "1" only if it hasn't received any data for the entire time interval, "0" otherwise.

For instance, .nodata(20m) on a 60sec item will return:

- 1: if no data received for the entire 20m time range (20 empty
  values)
- 0: if everything's ok (20 full values)
- 0: for everything
  inbetween (ie: 5 ok, 5 minutes of unreach, 10 ok)

I have found workaround, assuming that you check the agent reachability every 60 seconds:

```
({TRIGGER.VALUE}=0 and {Template App Zabbix Agent:agent.ping.nodata(5m)}=1) or ({TRIGGER.VALUE}=1 and {Template App Zabbix Agent:agent.ping.count(20m,1)}<20)
```

The expression will trigger after 5 minutes of unreachability and recover only when you have 20 "1" values in the last 20 minutes.

Not too elegant, but it works.

Comment: It does indeed work thank you :) No more flapping!! Will try and work out how to make that work with the new recover feature of v3.2 triggers